# Find the median between ranges

Tags: statistics

I have a list of ranges like this:
[0.1,0.2], [0.25,0.36], [0.6,0.69], [0.52,0.75], [0.65,0.96] ....

And I want to find the median range between these range in order to it divide that list into two sub-lists: {[left]...} < [median] < {[right]...}, and if we can do it, how can we identify which range is closest to the median range?

Comment: So, your values are actually $$0.1, 0.11, 0.09, 0.23, 0.31, \dots$$ if I get right and you want to find the median of these values? Am I right?

Comment: @Jimmy R: I mean that I have the list of ranges like that: $0.1 < X < 0.2$; $0.25 < Y < 0.36$ ... and I want to find the "median range" between these ranges. So can we do it or we just can do it if it must be list of numbers?

Comment: This is exactly what I wrote. The list of ranges is a list of numbers. The first range/number is $0.2-0.1=0.1$ the second $0.36-0.25=0.11$ and so on. Do you mean something else?